# MySQL: delete from IN

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1093

I know this is a simple syntax issue.  Trying to delete all users from a subquery:

```
delete from users
where id IN (

select u.id
from users u 
where not exists (select * from stickies i where i.user_id = u.id) 
group by u.email 
having count(*) > 1

)
```

Getting this error:

```
error : You can't specify target table 'users' for update in FROM clause
```

The subquery works fine (returns list of user id's).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DELETE u.*
FROM users u JOIN (
    SELECT u.id
    FROM users u LEFT JOIN stickies i ON i.user_id = u.id
    WHERE i.user_id IS NULL
    GROUP BY u.email 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
  ) r ON r.id = r.id
```

Note: in the inner query, you are grouping by email, but selecting a user ID. this may return non deterministic results.

Comment: Hmmm.  disturbing.  Got that query from here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985183/mysql-find-duplicate-users-where-item-count-1

Comment: @jmccartie Sorry, i misspelled `uid`

Comment: I'll tweak the subquery.  THanks!

Comment: @jmccartie I Guess if you are deleting duplicates, you don't care which user you are deleting. However it is more appropriate to use `MIN(u.id) id` or `MAX(u.id) id`.